# How to merge values of a single hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

Is there any way to merge values of a single hash?

Example:

```
address = { 
    "apartment" => "1",
    "building" => "Lido House",
    "house_number" => "20",
    "street_name" => "Mount Park Road",
    "city" => "Greenfield",
    "county" => nil,
    "post_code" => "WD1 8DC"
}
```

Could we get an outcome which looks like this?

```
1 Lido House,
20 Mount Park Road,
Greenfield,
WD1 8DC
```

address.compact will remove the value which equals nil, but what if in a method you include string interpolation and you want to exclude the nil value for some addresses and include it for others without a comma at the end?

```
def address(hash)
    hash.compact
    puts "#{hash["apartment"]} #{hash["building"]}, \n#{hash["house_number"]} #{hash["street_name"]}, \n#{hash["city"]}, \n#{hash["county"]}, \n#{hash["post_code"]}"
end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? One possible solution is going through every key in hash concatenating the value strings.

Comment: You've changed the question, after everyone answered it!! To summarise: No, there's no "magic" way for ruby to just *know* how the string should be formatted, if some values are `nil`. You need to write this logic yourself, but it's not very complicated. Just create a `result` variable, and append to it based on some simple conditionals. Your use of `Hash#compact` is also unnecessary (and isn't even doing anything!).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of deleting the question and reposting, but since it was already answered, I thought I'd give credit to those who did.

I have done something similar to what you suggested, except I did not create a variable and append to it.

I'm still learning and was trying to figure out alternative ways of answering the question before I submitted it. 

What happened to the tech community being understanding?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the values in a string:

```
"#{address['house_number']} #{address['street_name']},\n#{address['city']},\n#{address['post_code']}"
```

You could also improve the formatting by making this a helper method, and using a HEREDOC:

```
def formatted_address(address)
  <<~ADDRESS
    #{address['house_number']} #{address['street_name']},
    #{address['city']},
    #{address['post_code']}
  ADDRESS
end
```

Usage:

```
address = { 
  "house_number" => 20,
  "street_name" => "Mount Park Road",
  "city" => "Greenfield",
  "post_code" => "WD1 8DC"
}

puts formatted_address(address)
  # => 20 Mount Park Road,
  #    Greenfield,
  #    WD1 8DC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [string formats](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-25).

```
"%{house_number} %{street_name},\n%{city},\n%{post_code}" % address
```

Comment: Note that this only works if your hash keys are **`Symbol`s**. OP's question uses `String`s for hash keys. If this is within a Rails project (i.e. you have `ActiveSupport`), a convenient method for this is [`Hash#symbolize_keys`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/symbolize_keys).

Comment: You're right. However, in Rails it would be a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, so it may work?

Comment: **If** it's a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` then yes, that would also work. (Hashes do not have indifferent access "by default" in Rails.) In OP's actual code example, you'd need to call `address.with_indifferent_access` to achieve this.

Comment: These hash keys *should* be symbols, IMO. Proper Ruby convention.